# How do I automatically resize a photo from smaller to larger on upload in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, file-upload

How do I automatically resize a photo from smaller to larger on upload in Wordpress? In case if i have image 500x500 and i need dimensions 700x600? I know i can resize it after i uploaded. I use Crop Thumbnails, Force Regenerate Thumbnails, Imsanity, Regenerate Thumbnails but non of this plugins not doing that on upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called upscale and you generally don't want to do it. Image quality will be much worse than you expect. Better practice is to upload bigger images and downscale them. Say, for Retina screens you want 2x the size so you upload 1000x1000px images and then downscale from it using pre-defined image sizes or plugins that do resizing on the fly, like this one https://wordpress.org/plugins/fly-dynamic-image-resizer/

Comment: Thanks for answering me, I know it is not good way, but my reporters upload photos and I don’t have much choice here. Is there a way to change their scale to for example 4: 3?

Comment: Got it. You can just add another image size using add_image_size() in functions.php or a small plugin. Just specify 700x600px and play with crop parameter to see what works best for you. It's literally 3 lines of code )

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/

Comment: I know it, but as i told before, i want image 5:4 for main image... box is 500x400 px... and when my journalists upload image 600x379 px image wordpress show standard uploaded image 600x379... Can you see my problem?

Comment: @FabrikaNovagodina I see, how exactly do they upload images? As galleries inside posts? And how do you display them on frontend?